# What are the things to follow to upgrade my android app to material design?

Tags: android, material-design

I want to update my old android application to support material design.Currently i'm using android eclipse to develop.I have following questions.

1.What are the things to follow to upgrade my android app to material design?

2.Do i need to use Android Studio to support for material design?

3.Is there any documentation about how to design material design?

4.Up to which older version does material design support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.What are the things to follow to upgrade my android app to material design?

All [definitions and guidelines in the Material Design site](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html). Personally, I believe the most important are the [Metrics and Keylines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-and-keylines.html) section, as well as the [Typography](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html) section. I mean, if I were to start learning Material Design, I would start there.

Of course, all other things are useful as well. For example, you *must* look at the Components group, and most important (in my humble opinion), [*how* and *when* to use Cards](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#) (compare to Tiles). Again, metrics and typography play a *huge* role here. Some other things seem to be more useful to people implementing widgets and all, i.e., system programmers and designers.

Floating Action Button (a component for [promoted actions](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/promoted-actions.html#promoted-actions-floating-action-button)), are also going to play a huge role in Material Design.

Finally, considering this is all very new, I strongly suggest you follow well known people on Google+, and subscribe to some communities there. There are new things, code samples and open source components appearing each day, that help easing this transition. One of the cool stuff I've found recently is one (“[LDrawer](https://github.com/ikimuhendis/LDrawer)“) that automatically deals with the icon morphing animation for the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. I don't even know if this has already been put into the support libraries (or as easily as a one line import/change), just for you to see how this is all so new. *Update: it is present in the support-v7 library now. Again, everything is changing very fast.*

[Android App Design](https://plus.google.com/communities/116667001535376136065) is a good one. [Roman](https://plus.google.com/113735310430199015092) [Nurik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102703/roman-nurik) is the moderator. There are good stuff that pops up on [Android Projects on Github](https://plus.google.com/communities/100609058582053363304), and so on…

> 2.Do i need to use Android Studio to support for material design?

No. But I suggest you at least *try* it. It's going to be the future, it has a lot of useful features, and it's the "kinda official" IDE for Android development. Everything is going to be released for it (first, or only).

I stopped following Eclipse for Android development quite some time ago, so I can't really comment on what you're missing there, but last I've heard, even one of the Googlers that really used Eclipse finally migrated a few weeks ago. Some jokes flew on Google+ because of that :), so I would take that as a hint. ;)

> 3.Is there any documentation about how to design material design?

See 1. If you mean the javadocs, see classes mentioned in the links posted in 4, below.

> 4.Up to which older version does material design support?

By using [a few support libraries](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7), you can use most of the components down to API 7 ([Eclair MR1/2.1](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels)), so that means [everything, in practice](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). Not all, but Google is certainly putting a lot of effort to backport everything as transparently as possible. IIRC, they said that in one of the I/O sessions when someone asked one of the presenters.

I say “as transparently as possible” because some things won't be there, because they depend on new stuff added in 5.0 (for example, the shadow rendering for cards). But these are, *as far as I know*, specific issues that don't affect development.

Indeed, here we are: 5.0 is not really in the wild yet, and we already have most stuff all the way back to v7.

Answer (score 2):

To use material design in your Android apps, follow the guidelines defined in the [material design specification](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#) and functionality available in Android 5.0 (API level 21)

So update android sdk to api 21.
and check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html)

Comment: appcompact v7 includes material design for lower version.

Comment: Which is fairly not complete. (Styling of dialogs, SeekBar, etc is missing.) So I would wait for an update.